# System.ArgumentException: The "RecursiveDir" name is reserved, and cannot be used

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild

I have a line in an csproj file:

```
<MSBuild Projects="..\WebUI\WebUI.csproj" Targets="_CopyWebApplication;_BuiltWebOutputGroupOutput" Properties="OutDir=%(WebOutputDir.FullPath);WebProjectOutputDir=%(WebOutputDir.FullPath)" />
```

that is throwing the error:

System.ArgumentException: The "RecursiveDir" name is reserved, and cannot be used.

I've managed to narrow it down to the one line, and I'm not sure how to resolve so that this builds.  This is a TFS 2015.3 server.  The project has been building successfully on a Bamboo server, we're moving to TFS.

Comment: I don't see enough information to resolve the issue. You probably need to post more information, such as the project file contents.

Comment: The targets being called aren't in the project file, _CopyWebApplication;_BuiltWebOutputGroupOutput are standard MSBuild targets, and there's no match for RecursiveDir in the WebUI project.  The project file is quite large.  I'm not sure which portion would be relevant.

Comment: Which build are using with TFS? XAML build or Vnext build? Could you build your project manually on your build agent machine?

Comment: Using VNext, I CAN build manually from VS 2015 on the TFS machine.

Comment: Also, if I remove "_BuiltWebOutputGroupOutput" the build succeeds, seems to be fine but I haven't had QA look at the result.

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting an [MSBuild bug](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/5225). To work around it, set the MSBUILDTARGETRESULTCOMPRESSIONTHRESHOLD environment variable to a high number, for example:

```
SET MSBUILDTARGETRESULTCOMPRESSIONTHRESHOLD=1000000
```

Comment: Any idea where this setting is? I looked into all folders in my solution and couldn't find this setting.